# mysql PDO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE calculate + x

Tags: mysql, pdo, mariadb

I use this query with MySQL (MariaDB) PDO

```
INSERT INTO count_to_user (userid, countid, count) 
    VALUES (?, ?, 1) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1
```

When I use it in phpmyadmin, the insert in the count is 1 when it's a new entry.

With PHP PDO the insert is 2.
What is my fault?
Sorry for my bad English

```
CREATE TABLE count_to_user (
    userid INT(10) NOT NULL,
    countid INT(10) NOT NULL,
    count INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    UNIQUE KEY (userid, countid)
);
```

Comment: Please specify which fields are Primary key or Unique key in your table ?

Comment: Sorry:CREATE TABLE count_to_user (
 userid INT(10) NOT NULL,
 countid INT(10) NOT NULL,
 count INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 UNIQUE KEY (userid, countid)
);

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53338545/edit) the question and add these details to the question itself.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: I have edit a minute before

Comment: Double check your code -- It sounds as if the PDO statement was executed twice.